# How to access an object attribute with a dot in its name

Tags: python

I am using a bunch class to transform a dict to an object.

```
class Bunch(object):
    """ Transform a dict to an object """
    def __init__(self, kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

The problem is , i have a key with a dot in its name({'test.this':True}).

So when i call:

```
spam = Bunch({'test.this':True})
dir(spam)
```

I have the attibute:

```
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
...
 '__weakref__',
 'test.this']
```

But i can't access it:

```
print(spam.test.this)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-ea63f60f74ca> in <module>()
----> 1 print(spam.test.this)

AttributeError: 'Bunch' object has no attribute 'test'
```

i got an AttributeError.

How can i access this attribute?

Comment: Since it hasn't been said yet: The actual solution would be to avoid dots in variable names and using `snake_case` instead. Unless you don't have the option to rename the variable.

Comment: @Arne I don't think dots must be avoided. There are valid uses cases for a class to behave like a dict and allow names that include dots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
>>> getattr(spam, 'test.this')
True
```

Alternatively, you can get the value from the object's `__dict__`. Use [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) to get `spam`'s dict:

```
>>> vars(spam)['test.this']
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement [`__getitem__(self, key)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?emulating-container-types#object.__getitem__):

```
class D():
    def __init__(self, kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__.get(key)


d = D({"foo": 1, "bar.baz": 2})

print(d["foo"])
print(d["bar.baz"])
```

**Edit:**

I don't recommend accessing `d.__dict__` directly from a client of a `D` instance. Client code like this

```
d = D({"foo": 1, "bar.baz": 2})
print(d.__dict__.get("bar.baz"))
```

is trying to reach into the underpants of `d` and requires knowledge about implementation details of `D`.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why `__getitem__` should appear in this answer. The relevant part is `self.__dict__.get`. It doesn't have to be in `__getitem__`. I'd recommend removing that. It might confuse some people.

Comment: `d.__dict__` should not be accessed by a client of a `D` instance.

Comment: That's true, but that doesn't mean that the class has to implement `__getitem__`. You could implement a `get_attribute` method instead or call it whatever you want. Your answer makes it look like implementing `__getitem__` is necessary for this to work.

Comment: Not necessary but recommended. Why invent `get_attribute` if `__getitem__` exists?

Answer (score 0):

A correct suggestion would be to avoid using dot in the variables.
And even if we use somehow, its better to get it using **getattr**.

```
getattr(spam, 'test.this')
```

If we are being stubborn by avoid standards so this may help.

```
class Objectify(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        for key in obj:
            if isinstance(obj[key], dict):
                self.__dict__.update(key=Objectify(obj[key]))
            else:
                self.__dict__.update(key=obj[key])


class Bunch(object):
    """ Transform a dict to an object """
    def __init__(self, obj, loop=False):
        for key in obj:
            if isinstance(obj[key], dict):
                self.__dict__.update(key=Objectify(obj[key]))
            else:
                self.__dict__.update(key=obj[key])


spam1 = Bunch({'test': {'this': True}})
print(spam1.test.this)

spam2 = Bunch({'test': {'this': {'nested_this': True}}})
print(spam2.test.this.nested_this)
```

Not provided **test.this** as the key. You may want to create a nested dict iterating through the keys having dots.

Answer (score -1):

Try spam["test.this"] or spam.get("test.this")